# (Beginner) Why am I getting this cannot find symbol error?

Tags: java

Here's my code

```
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class assignment4 {

         public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a");
        double aa = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter b");
        double bb = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter c");
        double cc = input.nextDouble();
        double discriminant = (bb * bb - 4 * aa * cc);
        discriminant = Math.power(discriminant,0.5);

        }
        }
```

I'm getting an error at this part.

```
        discriminant = Math.power(discriminant,0.5);
```

What could I be doing wrong? This is the error btw

```
assignment4.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
discriminant = java.lang.Math.power(discriminant,0.5);
                             ^
  symbol:   method power(double,double)
  location: class Math
1 error
```

Comment: You can't just change your question into another question. This makes posted answers invalid. If you have new problem post new question (you can include link to this one if you think it is relevant).

Comment: Oh sorry didn't realize that was a rule. It's because there was a cooldown on posting another question, that's why

Comment: Cooldown is there for a reason. It is set to give asker time to spend on research, like in case of this question. If you would spend some time to search for `Math` class documentation you would find that there is no `power` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that you need to be using is `Math.pow(discriminant, 0.5)`

Comment: Wow that was so simple. Thank you so much